# @Autowired dependencies is not getting initialized in base class

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have a test class which is testing an other class method

Other class is structured like this

```
@Component 
public abstract class ParentOpManager{
     @Autowired 
     private ProcessorRequestWrapper processorRequestWrapper;

     @Autowired 
     private XYProcessor xyProcessor;

}

@Component("childManager")
public class ChildOperationManager extends ParentOpManager{

}

public abstract class ParentClass{
       protected final RequestWrapper requestWrapper;
       protected final ParentOpManager parentOpManager;


       public ParentClass(final RequestWrapper requestWrapper, final ParentOpManager parentOpManager){
           this.requestWrapper = requestWrapper;
           this.parentOpManager = parentOpManager;
       }
}
```

further I have, child classes extending this class

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{

      @Autowired 
      private NinjaManager ninjaManager;

      @Autowired
      public ChildClass(final RequestWrapper requestWrapper, @Qualifier("childManager")final ParentOpManager parentOpManager){
          super(requestWrapper, parentOpManager);
      }

      public void methodA() throws Exception {
          Request item = requestWrapper.findItem(); // Problem place 1
      }

      public void methodB() throws Exception {
          Request item = ninjaManager.findItem(); // Problem place 2
      } 
}
```

I need to test methods of `ChildClass`. For this I have written a test class.

```
//@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration
public class TestClass{

    @Mock 
    ChildOperationManager chOpManager;

    @Mock 
    RequestWrapper requestWrapper;

    @InjectMocks
    ChildClass childObject;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }        

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodA() throws Exception{
        childObject.methodA();
    }
}
```

So, the problem is when I am class methodA from test class, requestWrapper is NULL. I can not understand why this is happening ?

EDIT:

If i do like

```
    @Mock 
    ChildOperationManager chOpManager = new ChildOperationManager();

    @Mock 
    RequestWrapper requestWrapper;

    @InjectMocks
    ChildClass childObject = new childObject(requestWrapper, chOpManager);
```

Problem seams to be resolved. There is some other problem which might be some permission issue. But do you think doing this way is good approach ?

Comment: How are you initialising the Spring Context in your unit test?

Comment: I think you should be running with `SpringJunit4Runner.class`

Comment: , Yeah, i didn't wrote it here. I am using @ContextConfiguration annotation, i have updated the code above.

Comment: Ofcourse it is null... You are expecting mocks to be injected but aren't actually creating any mocks to inject... Hence it will be null. Also only using `@ContextConfiguratin` is pretty much useless, it doesn't do anything without the `SpringJUnit4Runner`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please look in the update TestClass . I am still getting NULL.

Comment: I am updating in a exiting code, earlier there was a single base class, now i have a parent class and base class. So this problem starts coming.

Comment: isn't it rather @InjectMocks (with an 's') ?  Also, ContextConfiguration doesn't do anything since you aren't loading a Spring context, you are using Mockito (as M. Deinum said)...

Comment: I don't think InjectMock exists (it's InjectMocks), Same with "PaterntClass " typo". This suggests are typing "new" code in the question as opposed to a "copy&paste". This leads me to wonder how much can we trust what you wrote in the question ? What are you leaving out ? Does the Parent class have a constructor?

Comment: Yes, it's @InjectMocks (with an 's') in original app. I am using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); now.

Comment: @alexbt Yes it has constructor, I have updated the code. It's very big code, and i don't know which part to include. Hope it's complete now.

Comment: still errors:  "public ParentClass(final requestWrapper, final ParentOpManager){"

Comment: Yes, that too. I have updated the code.

Comment: publlic ChildClass  => public class ChildClass

Comment: One problem in code above `ChildOperationManager` is not extends `ParentOpManager`. But I'm not sure is it issue or not

Comment: sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: You're hiding requestWrapper from ChildClass  with final requestWrapper from ParentClass. Try to rename requestWrapper in ChildClass and see what exacly requestWrapper  is nulli

Answer (score 1):

Your error is this:

```
@Autowired
public ChildClass(final RequestWrapper requestWrapper, @Qualifier("childManager")final ParentOpManager parentOpManager){
    super(requestWrapper, parentOpManager);
}

public void methodA() throws Exception {
    Request item = requestWrapper.findItem(); // this requestWrapper is null 
}
```

You don't assign the requestWrapper reference  in the child. So it remains null.

You should just remove the member variable `requestWrapper` and `parentOpManager` from the child. this way, you'll use the parent's one, which is initialized.

Comment: Yes, what you are saying makes sense. I did this but getting the same problem. However, edit code with new seams to solve problem. Not sure if that's right approach/

Comment: I tried with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) , value of requestWrapper is still NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that Mockito tried to inject mock via constructor in first step.

```
public class DefaultInjectionEngine {

public void injectMocksOnFields(Set<Field> needingInjection, Set<Object> mocks, Object testClassInstance) {
    MockInjection.onFields(needingInjection, testClassInstance)
            .withMocks(mocks)
            .tryConstructorInjection() <-- Here
            .tryPropertyOrFieldInjection()
            .handleSpyAnnotation()
            .apply();
}
```

}

And if it found proper constructor, it doesn't try to inject mocks via property or field.

In your case you have constructor for ChildClass, which was picked by Mockito, but you don't initialize a fields in ChildClass.

As workaround, you can resolve it in this way (just don't use mockito injections):

```
RequestWrapper wrapper;
ChildOperationManager childOperationManager;
ChildClass childObject;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    wrapper = Mockito.mock(RequestWrapper.class);
    childOperationManager = Mockito.mock(ChildOperationManager.class);
    childObject = new ChildClass(wrapper, childOperationManager );
}
```

Comment: removing field requestWrapper from ChildClass works in my code fine. Is RequestMapper mocked in test class?

Comment: workaround could be as you already described. `ChildClass childObject = new ChildClass(mock(RequestWrapper.class), mock(ChildOperationManager.class);` in `@Before` method

Comment: @saurabhagarwal What verions of Mockito are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.10

Comment: "but you don't initialize a fields in ChildClass." Can you explain this a bit further ? childclass is calling the parent class, which is setting the field ..

Comment: @saurabhagarwal yes but in previous version you also has requestWrapper in ChildClass but never set any value to it